# Book about generalized linear models

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, references

Does anyone know a good book about generalized linear models. I am a practitioner and need to master the concepts of generalized linear model, but also my experience tells me that knowing about the background math equations will also be a great help. So to sum it up I am looking for a book (or books) which gives a great intuition about the concepts and also I am looking for a book which explains the equations from A to Z. Below I have written my agenda from most important to least. Please if you know a good reference for each, tell me. Thanx

1. Generalized linear models' concepts
2. Generalized linear models' equations
3. Alternatives for logistic regression for correlated data (equations, concepts and everything!)